# KeyValueStore Interface

Tags: java, key-value, distributed-system

Hi have the following interface:

```
public interface KeyValueStore {
    public void put(String key, byte[] value);
    public byte[] get(String key);
    public void putAll(Map<String,byte[]> pairs);
    public Map<String,byte[]> getAll(Collection<String> keys);
}
```

And I have the following client that implements the previous interface:

```
public class Client implements KeyValueStore{

    @Override
    public void put(String key, byte[] value) {
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] get(String key) {
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<String, byte[]> pairs) {

    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, byte[]> getAll(Collection<String> keys) {
    }
}
```

How can I implement the Client in order to interact with the given interface? I want to do this with a client-server architecture.

Another thing I want is a "name server" that knows where the data is stored (basically it has the mapping of keys to "storage servers"), and several other servers where the data is actually persisted.

Comment: This interface looks like a proxy class to a HashMap...  Wouldn't you just fill in each method and make the call in an internal HashMap Member in Client?

Comment: The client could just be a no-op implementation. To fullfill it return null on get and getAll

Comment: I would expect the _server_ to implement the interface, not the client.  Are you asking about how to remote the put/get calls from the client to be run on a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite an open-ended question. I'll take a shot at it.

I think you need to keep three different concepts in mind:

Interface
Implementation
Client

Let's look at each one.
You have the interface already, so it's all good on that part.

What you're calling the client, I believe to be the implementation, meaning: it's the actual code that implements the behavior of the methods defined in your interface.

A client (in my interpretation), would be yet another piece in your system, that interacts with your Interface through the implementation that you'll write.

Addressing your question:
First step would be figuring out how you'll persist the data introduced through put and putAll. If you just want to keep some stuff in memory, then a Map will probably suffice. If the number of entries is expected to grow alot, then you probably want to make the implementation interact with a database (or other form of persistence).

Does this add some light on your question? Add some more details, and I'll give more insight if I can.

Hope it helps.

**Edit:**

A distributed storage system has quite a few variables brought to the table.

Do you have a centralized endpoint that then chooses where the data will be stored in some way (round-robin or some more complex algorithm)?

How will the clients interact with your system? Is it a web-based system, RMI, something else?

I think you need to focus on the basic architecture before thinking of the actual implementation, since the main problems with a system like this is robustness and handling flaws.

One possibility is having a "name server" that knows where the data is stored (basically it has the mapping of keys to "storage servers"), and several other servers where the data is actually persisted. You need to choose how these will communicate between them, or if each server will be both a "name server" AND a "storage server"... there's really a lot of possibilities here!

Comment: Well, what I want to do is as a distributed data storage. Each data item must be stored persistently in disk in one of several remote servers.

Comment: Edited answer with some more thoughts.

Comment: Yes, thats the idea. I want a "central server" that will map the keys from the other servers. For instance I will have from "a to f" on Server1 and from "f to z" on other server.

Comment: I see that you are Portuguese, so am I xD. Could you give me one IM contact that you use so I can speak with you about this topic?

Answer (score 1):

The most basic implementation would be to use an internal `Map`, but it's a bit silly, why don't you use a `Map` in the first place?

```
public class Client implements KeyValueStore{
    private final Map<String, byte[]> internalMap = new HashMap<String, byte[]>();

    @Override
    public void put(String key, byte[] value) {
        this.internalMap.put(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] get(String key) {
        return internalMap.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<String, byte[]> pairs) {
        internalMap.putAll(pairs);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, byte[]> getAll(Collection<String> keys) {
        return internalMap.keySet();
    }
}
```

So I'm not sure that's what you want. Do you want a client-server architecture? If so, please mention it clearly in your question, with the specifications you want.

Comment: Yes I want a client-server architecture

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are asking here but I'll assume you want the client to implement an interface and remote the calls to a server which also implements the interface.  Here are my thoughts:

1. You need to choose a remoting technology.  [RMI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html) is a easy choice.  Some sort of HTTP client/server is another possibility.  Here's a [simple UDP client/server](http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-udp-server-and-udp-client/).  Here are [some more ideas](http://pirate.shu.edu/~wachsmut/Teaching/BMIS7111/sockets.html).
2. On the server you will have to do something with the data.  An obvious one would be to just have a local in-memory `HashMap`.  Using a SQL database like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) would be an easy way to persist it.  [Berkeley DB JE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index-093405.html) is another.
3. The hardest part of the problem is figuring out how you are going to to distribute the requests somehow.  You could take the `hashCode()` value on the client and divide up the hash space between servers.  For example, you can take the `hashCode()` integer and mod it by the number of servers.  That value will be the server to send it to.  If the number of servers changes then you would need to re-mod everything unfortunately.  You could send the `put` requests to a random server and then send all of the `get` request to all of the servers and wait for all of the responses.  That takes some thread fu however unless you do it serially.